# Factory Boy date provider is returning string

Tags: python, django, date, factory-boy

So, I've been working in some app using the factory_boy package to generate some random data and I'm suffering with the date provider :(

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()

class MyModelFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    date = factory.Faker('date')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

my_model = MyModelFactory()
my_model.date # '2010-05-20'
```

Someone know how can I make the faker return a real date object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `date` provider returns a string - not a `date` object. You need to use the [`date_object` provider](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers/faker.providers.date_time.html#faker-providers-date-time) instead:

```
class MyModelFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    date = factory.Faker('date_object')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `Faker('date_object')`, or — for more control — the [`factory.fuzzy.FuzzyDate` helper](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fuzzy.html#fuzzydate):

```py
class MyModelFacotry(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    # Start somewhere in 2018
    start_date = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyDate(
        datetime.date(2018, 1, 1),
        datetime.date(2019, 12, 31),
    )
```

Comment: Note: https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fuzzy.html
Fuzzy is being deprecated

Comment: Note: https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fuzzy.html Fuzzy HAS BEEN deprecated

Comment: I'm the core dev of factory_boy, so I know what is or isn't deprecated ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert it to a date as soon as you get it.

```
date = datetime.strptime(factory.Faker('date'), "%b-%d-%y")
```